# Trying to get values from options using stmt->bind_result; causing fatal error (out of memory)

Tags: php, mysqli

Just like the title says, I am trying to fetch the meta_keys and meta_values from database using mysqli fetch stmt.  The error I am getting is saying out of memory, and references this line in my code:

```
//Bind result variables
$select_stmt->bind_result($id, $key, $value);
```

Im not really sure where or what I am doing wrong, this is that function in its entirety.  My goal is to call the function in another file and pass the userID and option(meta_key) that I would like to retrieve the meta_value for.

```
function get_options($userid, $option) {
    global $mysqli;


    $query = "SELECT user_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM user_settings WHERE user_id = ? AND meta_key = ? LIMIT 4";

    if($select_stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {

        $select_stmt->bind_param('ss', $userid, $option);

        //Execute the prepared statement
        $select_stmt->execute();

        //Bind result variables
        $select_stmt->bind_result($id, $key, $value);

        //Fetch the values
        while ($select_stmt->fetch()) {
            printf($key, $value);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `printf($key, $value);` that can't be right... PHP is using the `$key` variable (bound to the resultset) as a printing format (string like `"foo %s => %s"`). either use `print`, `printf("%d, %s", $key, $value); ` or something else entirely

Comment: Thanks, it does say that clear as day here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php so my bad; unfortunately that does not solve this out of memory issue.  I also have tried using ini_set("memory_limit") and giving it some ridiculous number, I just dont understand what could be causing it to be out of memory if it is a simple query?  Maybe Im doing something wrong..

Answer (score 0):

I got it, here is what worked for me, hope it helps someone else out:

```
function get_options($userid, $option) {
    global $mysqli;

    if ($select_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT user_id, meta_key, meta_value, salt 
          FROM user_settings 
          WHERE user_id = ? AND meta_key = ?")) {
        $select_stmt->bind_param('ss', $userid, $option);
        $select_stmt->execute();   // Execute the prepared query.
        $select_stmt->store_result();

        // Execute the prepared query.
        if (! $select_stmt->execute()) {
            echo 'Could not perform option query on database';
        }

        // If the user exists get variables from result.
        $select_stmt->bind_result($userID, $key, $value, $salt);
        $select_stmt->fetch();

        echo ' ID is '.$userID.'<br />';
        echo ' Key is '.$key.'<br />';
        echo ' Value is '.$value.'<br />';
        echo ' Salt is '.$salt.'<br />';


    } //end if($select_stmt) 


}
```

In the above you will see I added store_result before binding the result and added the fetch property after binding the results.